# What is the root error behind "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

Looking through google and stackoverflow, I found a number of questions asking about "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password." However, I cannot find anyone that has found what the underlying error is.

I am trying to write my first google script with a database connection; I have a mysql and oracle jdbc getConnection, both of which spawn this error. I have checked, double- and triple-check the connection information to no avail. I know the databases are accessible (can get in through other clients from several different machines like php on a linux box, sql developer on various windows PCs at home and work). How do I determine what the real error is? The error as presented to me is way too generic and abstract.

Environment:
Using a script in a Google Spreadsheet (thus inheriting whatever environment is established by google). I am attempting to use the Google API jdbc and have no further knowledge of the environment variables.

Using the following syntax:

```
var url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.cb-pta.com:3306/u4lottery";
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Again, user and password have been verified.

Comment: Wrong connection string, wrong username or wrong password. Hard to determine, when we don't have a clue what connection string you are using.

Comment: my guess is you got the user name and password right - so probably the connection string.  maybe check your environment variables

Comment: (can get in through other clients from several different machines) what other clients? How are they configured to connect?

Comment: None of these suggestions tell me how to find the root error.

I apologize about the lack of contextual information; I had assumed that most of that would have been filled out via my link from google scripts. I see that it was not, so I'll edit the original.

Comment: There is a known bug which causes problems with jdbc connections using hostnames. Try using an Ip address instead.

Comment: @mgmonteleone: thanks, that fixed the mysql connection issue but not the oracle issue. That is a pretty serious bug - is it new?

Comment: Also, @a_horse_with_no_name, you removed my 'oracle' tag? No oracle love?

Comment: @sacrophyte: I don't see how this question relates to Oracle as it is only MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: "I have a mysql and oracle jdbc getConnection"; I did not post the url details for the Oracle connection because I prefer that folks not go look at the server (I am not sure it is secured). I can provide a generic Oracle connect string, but does that really help?

Comment: After retyping the Oracle section with IP numbers, the Oracle code is now working as well. Don't know what the original problem was - the original looks the same to me.

When will the bug with dns name resolution be fixed with Google Scripts?

Comment: @mgmonteleone: if you want to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a known bug which causes problems with jdbc connections using hostnames. Try using an Ip address instead.

Bizarre, but true.. I lost almost 2 days with this bug....

[Here is the link to the bug report....](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=1856)

Comment: Thanks. This answers one of my questions, but I kinda suspect that I will never find out how to view beneath the covers of google-scripts to find what this generic error covers.

Comment: Hi, I have used IP address then also it is resulting same error again and again

Comment: @sacrophyte can you please tell me how did you get that IP address? I have a database created in Google Cloud SQL

Comment: Fixed my problem after 1 day of debug :D thanks a lot

Comment: Even after 10 years, this answer still holds true!!

Answer (score 3):

Just for sake of others finding this older thread.  I also had trouble using Apps Script to connect to a Google CloudSQL instance, and had to change from:

```
Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection('jdbc:google:rdbms://<IP>/<DB_NAME>', '<USER>', 'PASSWORD');
```

to standard JDBC MySQL (which worked):

```
Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql:// ...same as above...
```

Also, beware and DO NOT include a '/' behind the DB_NAME - this will also cause failure with user/passwd error message!

One more thing to check is that you have proper firewall settings - to allow access from the source IP you are coming from *(in the event of Apps Script, this is likely Google's servers - not you client browser's IP)*.  You may have to open it up to all (0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: if I use "jdbc:mysql" i get "Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol."

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with your database being behind a firewall. According to [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031) (in this case, Google Data Studio, but generally applicable): "If your database is behind a firewall, you will need to open access to the all of the following IP addresses. These are used by Data Studio to connect to and query your MySql database."

IP addresses here among other places: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031