# jdbc connection errors from Google Script

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Anyone out there who could help me?  I have been bashed over two straight days by failed connection requests from an Google Apps Script to a mysql db hosted on Dreamhost.  Have had extensive support from Dreamhost but no solution.  Have concluded the failure to connect is the same issue confronted by many in [existing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201632/jdbc-connection-error-from-google-apps-script).

All I want to do is collect internal business data in Google sheets and load into a tables in my cloud sql db.  Problems could be attributable to either a bug or an IAM permissions issue.  My account is owner of the GSuite orgaqnization, and I also granted it explicit role for Cloud SQL Client.  In connection requests, I've tried using both host URL and the host IP to connect.  Neither worked and I am frustrated.  Any ideas?

```
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://mysql.url.com:3306/db_name','user','password')
```

Thanks in advance for any help or recommendations.  CW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: Thank you for trying but unfortunately it does not.  I am such a noob that it doesn't make sense...