# SQL Server with Google Apps Script via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

There seems to be an issue with Google Apps Script `JDBC Connection` in recent days, where connection via a hostname fails, but specifying an IP works.

Error:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string,
>   username and password.

```
    function SQLTOGOOGLOOGLESPREADSHEET(sqlQuery) {
    var address = 'http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/:3306';
    var user = 'root';
    var userPwd = '';
    var db = 'employee';
    var msSqlUrlSyntax ='jdbc:sqlserver://'

    var dbUrl = msSqlUrlSyntax + address + ';databaseName=' + db;

    // msSqlUrlSyntax = 'youOptionalTestingQuery'
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done it right. Using an IP address instead of hostnames work as workaround. This is a known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=1856). Also, this issue was cited in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331675/what-is-the-root-error-behind-failed-to-establish-a-database-connection-check).