# Google Script Error - Exception: You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-developers-console

I am running the Google Script

```js
function doCalc(p1,p2)
{
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://<domain>/<path>/appsscript.js').getContentText());
  return appObject(p1,p2).resultA;
}
```

and I get the result when I run it in Google Sheets / App Scripts editor after deploying it
5:05:52 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:05:52 PM  Error
Exception: You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection. Required
permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice
appObject
revisedMarkup   @ code.gs:4

The appsscript.js code which runs in the Google Cloud Platform is

```js
function appObject(p1,p2)
{

// Connnect GCP ......
var connectionName = '<connection name>';
var user = '<user>';
var userPwd = '<user passwd>';
var db = '<database name>';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
// .... End Connnect GCP
                            
var obj = {
  resultA: <calculation 1>,
  resultB: <calculation 2>
};
return obj;
}
```

Any idea how to solve the issue (i.e. the exception: You do not have permission...) above? I am a novice. I have given myself Cloud SQL Admin
and Owner permissions in the IAM in console.cloud.google.com.

Comment: Are you using this as a custom function? (Custom formula in the sheet). If yes, then that's the answer to your issue.

Comment: No, in my sheet I have =doCalc(I2,Q2) in one of the cells, where doCalc, as I said, is an Apps Script function. I deploy it and run it in Sheets script error (and then see the error).

Comment: A custom function is a function you deploy in the cells of a spreadsheet that you wrote yourself.

Comment: Hi ! Is it working if you run this from the script editor? Also, if you simply run ```appObject``` (with two valid params) does it work or does it return the same error?

Comment: Hi Mateo! If I call appObject directly from script editor, I get Error 
Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. I'm now stuck on that error as I have checked and re-checked the connection name, username, password and database name.

Comment: Does the user you are using to connect to the database have full priviledges to this db (i.e same priviledges as root)? Also, if you change your hostname with your IP address as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363515/12835757) are you able to connect ?

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm on my way to solving this. I will post my answer when I'm 100% sure for everyone to benefit.